# What is the purpose of "IO38_DBLTAP" on this ESP32-S3-MINI dev board?

Tags: microcontroller, power, esp32, gpio, adafruit

I was examining the Adafruit ESP32-S3-TFT feather board and saw this IO38_DBLTAP section (bottom right of image).

[image]

It looks like a pulldown resistor and a decoupling capacitor, but I'm confused as to why they are connected to a GPIO pin.
Is there something special about pin IO38? In the other adafruit S3 feather board they did a similar thing, except connecting it to IO34 (named IO34_DBLTAP respectively).

Looking at the ESP32-S3-MINI datasheet, they seem to be regular GPIO pins (image below).

[image]

Comment: Looks like part of the [Adafruit "double-tap" reset](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-esp32-s2-feather/install-uf2-bootloader) UF2 Bootloader logic.